# Pandas DF - Create incremental sequence based on a condition without for loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sequence

I need help with an issue I have concerning the creation of a sequence.

The sequence should be based on the value of 
`ID_PROJET_test` field that contains a bool which indicates whether we should increment or not.

if `ID_PROJET_test = False` then increment
if `ID_PROJET_test = True` then do not increment

For instance, if `ID_PROJET_test` contains the following Series: `s1 = [0,0,1,0,1,0]`

`ID_PROJET` should be equal to : `[1,2,2,3,3,4]`

`If ID_PROJET_test` contains the following Series: `s2 = [0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0]`

`ID_PROJET` should be equal to : `[1,2,3,3,3,3,4,5]`

I can do it easily with a `for` loop :

```
compteur = 1
for i in range(len(df)):
    if df['ID_PROJET_test']==True:
        df.ID_PROJET[i] = compteur
    else:
        compteur += 1
        df.ID_PROJET[i] = compteur
```

However, I have around 1.8M records and it is much too slow.
Any idea on how to do it?

Answer (score 4):

If you flip the 0/1 value, you can use `cumsum()`:

```
s1 = pd.Series([0,0,1,0,1,0])

(~s1.astype(bool)).cumsum()
0    1
1    2
2    2
3    3
4    3
5    4
dtype: int64

s2 = pd.Series([0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0])

(~s2.astype(bool)).cumsum()
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    3
4    3
5    3
6    4
7    5
dtype: int64
```

Also note @Jon Clement's more compact:

```
(s1 ^ 1).cumsum()
```

Comment: Even simpler `(s1 ^ 1).cumsum()`

Comment: Just to note as well - you don't need the `astype(int)` in your version - it's just an unnecessary type conversion... True is 1 and False is 0 - so `cumsum`ing 'em works just fine and really increases the performance... it's still not as fast as xor'ing but much better :)

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Perfect !

Comment: @Arthur_V you're welcome!  Please mark this answer accepted by clicking the check to the left of the answer - that way others will know this problem has been resolved.